# How do I prevent php from converting string to integer/float?

Tags: php, string, integer

I'm trying to process/parse a text file that contains UPC codes for products. Every time I read the file, my UPCs are being converted to exponential notation. How can I prevent this? 
(I've tried settype() but it gets ignored.)

```
<?php
//input: 46563,,840253044815,106 12200-0 3-WAY LAMP ASTON BRONZE 29x21x16 1-150M,07/06/2007,07/06/2007,NONSTOCK,0,0,,AMBIENCE,AMBIENCE
$lines = file ('./scripts/fullproductlist.csv');
$newlinedata = "";
$count = 0;
// Loop through array, 
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    settype($linedata, "string");
    $linedata = explode (",", "$line");
    $count1++;
    echo "Line:".$count1."::".$line."\n"; //Output new line
}
    //output: 46563,,8.40253E+11,106 12200-0 3-WAY LAMP ASTON BRONZE 29x21x16 1-150M,7/6/2007,7/6/2007,NONSTOCK,0,0,,AMBIENCE,AMBIENCE
?>
```

Comment: show ..us ...the code

Comment: It's possible that the UPC's are being converted to exponential notation; more likely that theyr'e numbers (integer or float), but that PHP is simply displaying them that way because of the size of the value...... but as we can't see any of your code, guessing is all that we can do

Comment: And you're absolutely positive that there's nothing else in the script, i.e you didn't e.g. post an abbreviated version?

Comment: Since you're exclusively doing string operations here, PHP should not convert to numbers and/or exponential notation at any point. Since the output does not correspond to your code there's likely more going on in your actual code...

Comment: This is all that there is for this particular script. It's a test script I wrote to try and resolve the issue.

Comment: Try `var_dump($line, $linedata)`, what does the data look like at those stages?

Comment: Should i do this in the loop or after it's complete?

Comment: Output:

string(127) "46563,,840253044815,106 12200-0 3-WAY LAMP ASTON BRONZE 29x21x16 1-150M,07/06/2007,07/06/2007,NONSTOCK,0,0,,AMBIENCE,AMBIENCE"
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "46563"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(12) "840253044815"
  [3]=>
  string(51) "106 12200-0 3-WAY LAMP ASTON BRONZE 29x21x16 1-150M"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "07/06/2007"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "07/06/2007"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "NONSTOCK"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
  [10]=>
  string(8) "AMBIENCE"
  [11]=>
  string(10) "AMBIENCE
"
}
Line:3::46563,,840253044815, etc

Comment: Then there's something else in the script ...or the input file. Not only is the output converted to exponential notation, the string in $line is also miraculously split and then joined again - very, very unlikely.

Comment: The script is above. The only thing changed from the original above is the var_dump line and the fact that I used a smaller sample file. (The original file has over 100,000 lines.)

So, from what VolkerK is suggesting there is something in the original file that is triggering the conversion to exponential notation?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that there's a behind-the-scene conversion at all; I still think that to be rather unlikely.I'd now search the original source for a literal `8.40253E+11`, e.g. via grep.

Comment: It doesn't contain those. Look at the code in the original post. The input has 840253044815 as the UPC. During the processing it converts to 8.40253E+11.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with the original file being the culprit. When I run the script on a small sample of the file it doesn't do the conversion. When I use the full file, it does. 
Could it be the size of the file? I don't see any funky characters in the file that would cause problems.

Comment: Here's my test script:

`
$x = "123";
var_dump($x);

$y = "321";
var_dump($y);

$a = array();
$a[$x] = $y;
var_dump($a);

foreach ($a as $key => $value)
{
   var_dump($key);
   var_dump($value);
}
`

and here's the output from PHP 7.4.15:

`
test.php:5:string '123' (length=3)

test.php:8:string '321' (length=3)

test.php:12:
array (size=1)
  123 => string '321' (length=3)

test.php:16:int 123

test.php:17:string '321' (length=3)
`

For line#16 I can't seem to get the key to remain a string.